# How can I make TYPO3 RTE blockstyles work in Edge?

Tags: typo3, microsoft-edge, rte

I have a really strange problem. I added a blockstyle to the RTE of my TYPO3 website. It works fine everywhere except in Edge. Even in IE 11 it is working fine.
In Edge the blockstyle section is inactive the whole time (grayed out).
When I put the cursor into a text which already has a blockstyle it shows "unknown block style".

I am confused and so far found no info about Edge handling the RTE blockstyles different. Did I make a mistake with my code or is it a bug of Edge?

My code in **RTE.ts**:

```
    RTE {
    default {
        contentCSS = path/to/RTE.css
        showButtons = blockstylelabel, blockstyle, formatblock, bold, orderedlist, unorderedlist, insertcharacter, link, findreplace, chMode, removeformat, undo, redo, about
        buttons {
            formatblock {
                removeItems = h4, h5, h6, pre, address, article, blockquote, footer, header, nav, div, aside, section, container
            }            
        }
    }
}
# configuration for introtext blockstyle
RTE.default.buttons.blockstyle.allowedClasses := addToList(introtext)
RTE.default.proc.allowedClasses := addToList(introtext)
RTE.classes.introtext.name = Introtext

# configuration for checkmarks blockstyle
RTE.default.buttons.blockstyle.allowedClasses := addToList(checkmarks)
RTE.default.proc.allowedClasses := addToList(checkmarks)
RTE.classes.checkmarks.name = USP Liste
```

Code in **RTE.css**

```
    /* Block styles */

p.introtext {
    font-size: 24px;
}

ul.checkmarks {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like Bug and should be fixed by the TYPO3 Core Team. The RTE should not has/need Browser Specific Configuration.

you could report the bug here :
https://forge.typo3.org/projects/typo3cms-core/issues
(you need to be signed in with your typo3.org account. before the page shows you the "new Issue" button.

Here is a list of things that help developers Find the Issue more quickly:
1) TYPO3 Version. (see the about module)
2) Installed Extensions (if your suspect they interact with the RTE)
3) Possible Javascript Errors. (press F12 and click the tab "Console") 
4) Steps to reproduce the Issue.

Comment: Thank you for the hint.
I looked there for an open issue but found none.
I also tried the TYPO3 demo http://demo.typo3.org/ and tested the blockstyles in Edge. They don't work either, so I am convinced that it is a TYPO3 issue and I will open an issue there.

Answer (score 0):

The TYPO3 issue was closed with the following comment:

> We are sorry, but we close this issue as now TYPO3 uses CKEditor and 
>   RTEHtmlarea is no more supported by TYPO3 .
>
> RTEHtmlarea development has stopped - it has been decoupled from the
>   core and its code is available on GitHub:
>   https://github.com/FriendsOfTYPO3/rtehtmlarea
>
> If you still need this fixed please create a PR on GitHub